# Double Integrals. Simple question, don't understand their wording.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation

Make a sketch of the region over which

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \int_0^{\sin(x)} dy$$

Would this be the same as

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 1 dx \int_0^{\sin(x)} 1 dy$$

Which simply evaluates to $(\pi/2)\sin(x)$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's right: $\int_a^b dx$ is a shorthand for $\int_a^b1dx$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was originally
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sin(x)} dy\, dx.$$

In that even, you are doing the double integral over the region $G = \{(x,y)|0\le y \le \sin(x), 0\le x \le 1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

It would evaluate to $1$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Integrate first with respect to $y$. We get $y$. Do the limit points substitution. We get $\sin x-0$. Now integrate $\sin x\,dx$, from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

An antiderivative of $\sin x$ is $-\cos x$. So our final result is $-(\cos(\pi/2))-(-\cos(0))$, which is $1$.

The double integral we are evaluating is $1$ over the region below $y=\sin x$, above the $x$-axis, from $x=0$ to $x=\pi/2$. This is half an arch of the sine curve, and has area $1$.

For the picture they are asking for, draw the sine curve, and shade in the region described above.

Comment: The first definite integral gives value $\sin x$. Now integrate with respect to $x$, $x=0$ to $x=1$. An antiderivative is $-\cos x$.

Comment: Limits got changed. We now get $1-\cos(\pi/2)=1$.

Comment: I know I'm the noob asking the question, but I think you're wrong there. Each would be (pi/2 - 0)(sin(x)-0) resulting in pi/2(sin(x))

Comment: No!!! You must integrate $dy$, get a function of $x$, and then integrate $dx$. This is an *iterated integral*. See ncmathsadist's post.

Comment: I would have to see exact wording, formatting. However, it seems clear that what is intended is a double integral expressed as an interated integral. The first integration gives us $y$. Evaluate at $\sin x$, take away result of evaluating at $0$. We get $\sin x$. Now we are integrating $\sin x\,dx$, from $0$ to $\pi/2$. We get $1$.

Comment: So there is a massive difference between:
$\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \int_0^{\sin(x)} dy$ and 
$\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \times \int_0^{\sin(x)} dy$?